# What workaround should be used to overcome issue with systemctl refusing to enable unit files that are symlinks?

Tags: debian, systemd, symlink

I have a package that will be updated soon but I know that some of the users will prefer using the old one. That's why I used an **update-alternatives** routine in the package. The problem is also that the newer package depends on a newer **unit** files.

To sum up,

```
dpkg -L mypackage-1.0
```

> ```
> /opt/mypackage-1.0/binary
> ```

```
dpkg -L mypackage-service-1.0
```

> ```
> /opt/mypackage-1.0/mypackage.service
> ```

Upon install `dpkg -i mypackage-1.0` will provide a single alternative to **mypackage** and `dpkg -i myservice-service-1.0` to **myservice-service**

These are interdependent.

```
dpkg -L mypackage-2.0
```

> ```
> /opt/mypackage-2.0/binary
> ```

```
dpkg -L mypackage-service-2.0
```

> ```
> /opt/mypackage-2.0/mypackage.service
> ```

Upon install `dpkg -i mypackage-2.0` will provide a new alternative (`/lib/systemd/system/mypackage.service -> /etc/alternatives/mypackage.service`) to **mypackage** and `dpkg -i myservice-service-2.0` to **mypackage-service**

The idea behind is to allow easy yet explicit switching between versions with `update-alternatives --config mypackage` and `update-alternatives --config mypackage-service`

The first part works well but the second part turned out to be an issue.
It [seems](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3010) like I cannot use symlinks to unit files (exactly what `update-alternatives --install` does).

I use **systemctl 215** on **Debian Jessie**.

I suppose the whole thing could be laid out differently from scratch.

Comment: Are the two units different in ways other than the command they start? Couldn’t you ship one unit which uses the alternative for the binary?

Comment: Sorry, as the Issue you linked to notes, this issue was fixed in a newer version of `systemd`.

Answer (score 1):

Until you can upgrade to a newer version of `systemd` where the issue is resolved, you'll have to use another mechanism besides `update-alternatives` to copy and move files instead of `symlink` them, as the behavior of `systemd` can`t be changed with the current version.